# How to add array to JSON object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create a json string that has an array element:

```js
var arrays = [0,1,2];
var obj = new Object();
obj.data = arrays;
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

I get this result:

```
{"data":{"0":0,"1":1,"2":2}}
```

I want this JSON string:

```
{"data": [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], "name":"number"}
```

How can I add an array element to a JSON Object?

Comment: Please, try to explain what you need to do with an example of data and expected output... Also, you can share your efforts with us...

Comment: What's your expected input and output?

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify`

Comment: There's no such thing as a "JSON Object". JSON is by its very definition a *string*. And an object is, well... an object. What you have in your question is the latter. If you stringify an object, you now have JSON. The misuse of these terms in your question really muddles up your desired input and output, compounded by the fact that you haven't shown any code or attempts to lead us in the right direction.

Comment: I edit this question. I am not good english, sorry to give a confusion.

Comment: I added your code example to a code snippet. If you run the snippet, you will see that the result is {"data":[0,1,2]}  not {"data":{"0":0,"1":1,"2":2}} like you state in your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `JSON.stringify` like so:

```js
var myObj = {"data": [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], "name":"number"};
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(myObj);

console.log(myJSON);
```

And you can convert it back using `JSON.parse`:

```js
var myObj = {"data": [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], "name":"number"};
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(myObj);

console.log(JSON.parse(myJSON));
```

Answer (score 1):

do `JSON.parse` it, and `JSON.stringify` it again:

```js
var json = '{"data": [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], "name":"number"}'
var obj = JSON.parse(json)

obj.data.push(100)

var newJson = JSON.stringify(obj)

console.log(newJson)
```

Answer (score 0):

To add new element into JSON Object, just use: 
`jsonObject.key = value;`

```js
// your Example
var myObj = {
    "data": [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 
    "name":"number"
}; 
 
console.log(myObj); 
// {"data": [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 
//  "name":"number"}

myObj.myArray = ["a","b","c"];
console.log(myObj); 
// {"data": [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 
//  "name":"number", 
//  "myArray":["a","b","c"]}
```